# Upload File Method with Certificate

Tags: c#, webclient

I was wondering if you could lend a hand. I am stuck with this code giving me the following error: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I have added an override method to the WebClient Class with the proper certificate:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate("E:\\NY Cert.cer"));
        return request;
    }
    public WebRequest asd(Uri addr)
    {
        return this.GetWebRequest(addr);
    }
}
```

I need to use the certificate to upload a file to a web server. So I was trying to use the WebClient UploadFile Method

```
WebClient my = new WebClient();
        byte[] responseArray = my.UploadFile("Web Server URL", "POST", "File");
```

Comment: My mistake wasn't calling the Override Method I called "MyWebClient"